# Python @contextmanager method that mimics open file method?

Tags: python, contextmanager

I am currently working on a `Session` class that should be started both normally or using a `with` statement. I also need to share some pseudo-global value for each session:

```
session1 = Session(a, b ,c)
session2 = Session(x, y, z)
session1.start()
# Using session1 with a global value here

with session2.start():
    # Using session2 with global value copy

# Coming back in session1 with the initial global value
```

To manage the global value thing, I ended up using the `Contextual` library. (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Contextual).

To manage the `start()` as a `@contextmanager`, I was trying to deal with the Python stack. But I know it can be tricky depending on Python version and interpreter.

I would like to do the same as `open()` which you can use both ways:

```
f = open('...')
with open('...') as f:
    # Read the file here.
```

Is it possible ? How should you do that ?

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: How are you accessing these global values? Also, your example using `open` will result in the original value of f being overwritten by the with statement and forgotten. That is the value of f after the with statement is the closed second file, not the open first one.

Comment: It doesn't seem possible with `@contextmanager`, but you could implement `__enter__/__exit__` on the session class (that's how it's done for files).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible with `@contextmanager`, but you can make your `Session` class a context manager directly like this:

```
class Session:
    # ...
    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.close()
    #...
```

The details are [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers). That's how it is done for files. For the 3-rd party classes, [`contextlib.closing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) may also be handy.